# He asked me or told me to

Tags: sentence-construction

Please help me with below sentences which one is correct to say?Or is there any specific condition where I can use both?

a) He asked me to call you hence I have called you.

b) He told me to call you hence I have called you.

Answer (score 2):

These are the relevant meanings from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> [ask](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ask):
>  to speak or write to someone saying that **you want them to do something**, to give you something, or to allow you to do something
>
> [tell](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell):
>  
>    - to say something to someone, often giving them information or **instructions**
>    - to **order** someone to do something

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct, but the meaning may be different depending on the context.

**Ask** is definitely a polite request.

**Tell** could be  giving instructions: for example, if you asked somebody how to contact the person you are speaking to, and they told you to call. **Tell** could also be giving an order: you are not calling because you want to, but because you don't have any choice- your boss, or maybe a mafia hit-man, told you to call.

Answer (score 0):

In *this context,* there's no difference whatsoever. Because you can also [*ask* someone to *do* something](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-use-say-tell-and-ask). It's like *telling* only.

He asked/told me to call you - the context is clear and, therefore, both are okay and understandable.

Comment: As @JavaLatte says, _ask_ is more polite than _tell_.